# Need to create dynamic sub-domain url with codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am creating school management web software in which there are four types of user super admin, admin, teacher and parent/student and I need to create unique url for all types of user.

Like school will register on main domain and super admin will approve them and provide unique url to login for demo purpose. Also when school will register in real the same process will follow.

I need to create unique url for each school name with school name added to url and need to provide this unique url to each school.

The unique url sholud also work with multiple parameters provided in url.

I have checked many question's answers but none is of my use.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are this different applications for each school ?
if not whats the problem to define your base url like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';` ?

Comment: No the application wiil be same but url will be different for each school. For ex. school name is test and my domain is www.school.com so url should be www.test.school.com. Is it possible?

Comment: try my suggestion above - i think this should work

Comment: Ok I try and let you know, thanks...

Comment: Ok currently I am working on localhost. And I've changed config base url but now how I'll create dynamic url like I've registered an school with name 'bright' and I want my url should look like 'http://localhost/bright.schoolcc/admin'. My complete project is under one folder schoolcc. Now How I'll create such url. Please help.

Comment: An application cannot automatically create domains without you first registering these domain. Why not settle for: `school.com/schoolname` like twitter usernames

Comment: Thanks for quick response but actually it is my software and I'll set it on multiple schools but complete software will wok on my hosting server so I don't want to create so many sub-domain as application and functionality is same for all schools so I need create simple url that looks like sub-domain url but will work like normal url or something like that. Is it possible?

Comment: No, all subdomains need to be registered first.

Comment: normally you should be able to configure a catch-all wildcard for your subdomain (*.yoursite.com) which points to your server